# How to execute django query from string and get output

Tags: django, subprocess, exec

I want to run a django query from a string and put the output into a variable

in my DRF project, the client sends a django query:

```
{'query': 'model.objects.all()'}
```

and I need to return the result of this query.
I tried using `exec('model.objects.all()')` but i can't assign the output to a variable, i also tried using `subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", 'model.objects.all()'], capture_output=True, text=True)` but `subrocess` doesn't find the model

Comment: Why you want to exec in subprocess?

Comment: to catch the output

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge amount of setting up needed before a process using Django models can work correctly. That's why `manage.py shell` exists.

If you want to perform Django operations outside the context of a Django server, write a [management command.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) You can then invoke it from the command line, from cron, from other Python scripts ... wherever.